# Call method B of class X from method A of class X?

Tags: php

Hl,

I have this class:

```
class X{

    public function A(){
    return $this->B;
    }

    public function B(){
    return "test";
    }
}
```

I need to get "test" so:

```
$test = new X();
echo var_dump($test->A());
```

=NULL. Notice: Undefined property: X::$B

I also found this way:

```
public function A(){
return self::B;
}
```

=NULL. Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'B'

Please how can I call method from method in same class?

Comment: `$this->B` would reference a property `$B`; `$this->B()` would reference a method `B()`.... note the brackets

Comment: @DannyPhantom thank you

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you, that was my problem. Brackets.. :)

Comment: @MarkBaker, do you want to put your answer as a solution so it can be marked as the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @DannyPahntom and @MarkBaker:

`$this->B()` not just `$this->B`

thanks guys!